# Event handler for a UserControl doesn't fire

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

My `UserControl` contains various controls. I made an event handler for its click event. I want the event handler to fire / be called when the user clicks anywhere on my user control.

This is the method I use to add my `UserControl` to my WinForms application.

```
private void addContact(some parameters here)
{
     //This is my usercontrol
     contactsListItem.contactsListItem contact = new contactsListItem.contactsListItem();

    //
    //some codes here
    //

    //Adding an event handler for the click event
    contact.Click += new EventHandler(contact_Click);

    //Adding the UserControl to my application
    flowLayoutPanel_contactsList.Controls.Add(contact);
}
```

The `contact_Click(...)` event handler should change the background of my `UserControl`. I have tried stepping into the code to see if the event handler fires and I found out that it doesn't fire no matter where I click on my `UserControl`.

I have searched through the internet. I encountered terms like delegate, subscribers and publishers.

What should I do to make the event handler for my `UserControl`'s click event to fire?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What is the structure of your user control? Click events are not bubbled in WindForms, hence if you are clicking on a control WITHIN your user control, the latter won't fire any Click event.

[image]

EDIT:

The simplest solution is to manually bubble the event from each child by attaching a handler in your user control:

```
child1.Click += new EventHandler(child_Click);
child2.Click += new EventHandler(child_Click);
child3.Click += new EventHandler(child_Click);
```

and inside child_Click fire off your Click event:

```
this.OnClick(e);
```

Comment: since that's the case, what should I do so that whenever I click on the controls within my UserControl, it will be like I'm clicking on the UserControl itself?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be on the right track however it is not clear what your `contact` here is. Typically you use delegates (essentially pointers to functions) for methods that have arguments to be passed:

```
if (bDeleteRdClick)
    DeleteRD.Click -= delegate { DeleteRDClick(this.Object); };
DeleteRD.Click += delegate { DeleteRDClick(this.Object); };
```

where you are sure to remove pre-existing delegates, otherwise they will 'stack-up', firing multiple methods when not required.

For the method above, using an `EventHandler` seems to me to be the right approach, but as I state above, a check on whether `contact` is of the correct type would not go unmissed:

```
if (this.contact.GetType() == typeof(RibbonButton))
{
    RibbonButton Rb = (RibbonButton)contact;
    Rb.Click += new EventHandler(contact_Click);
}
```

I hope this is of some help.